# Ruby gems installer keeps saying that I am on an incompatible architecture

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I was trying to install [ocra](https://github.com/larsch/ocra) through ruby gems when it prompted me with this message:

```
gem install ocra
Ignoring strscan-3.0.4 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine strscan --version 3.0.4
```

As instructed, I ran the command, `gem pristine strscan --version 3.0.4`, and tried to install another gem. Unfortunately, when I tried to install rails, with `gem install rails`

```
<internal:/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': dlopen(/Users/myname/.gem/gems/strscan-3.0.4/lib/strscan.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/myname/.gem/gems/strscan-3.0.4/lib/strscan.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')) - /Users/myname/.gem/gems/strscan-3.0.4/lib/strscan.bundle (LoadError)
```

What popped out to me was the part where it says "incompatible architecture":

```
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e'))
```

I ran `arch` and got back:

```
arm64
```

I also tried running `gem` but got the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you upgrade from an x86_64 Mac to an ARM one? If so, trash your whole `rbenv` install and rebuild. You may also need to expunge Homebrew, too, if you're using that, to start from a clean slate. Otherwise the compiler will try, and fail, to incorporate x86_64 libraries into new builds which are ARM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to run from a Mac, ocra can only be run on Windows, source: https://github.com/larsch/ocra#requirements